# Julia - Function to search for rows which have all columns missing and delete those rows

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to find a similar functionality like in Python where in I can delete the rows which have ‘all’ null values in a row -

code in python - Using Pandas dataframe ‘closed_prices’

```
closed_prices.dropna(axis=0, how=‘all’, inplace=True)
```

Basically I want to drop rows which have missing values for all columns - I am using a stock data and want to remove the weekends and holidays, each column represent closing price of a particular stock. So if all the column values are null/missing for a particular row I want to delete that row.

I am using the below code -

```
using DataFrames
using DataFramesMeta
using CSV
using Dates
using Query


fh_5 = CSV.read("D:\\Julia_Dataframe\\JuliaCon2020-DataFrames-Tutorial\\fh_5yrs.csv", DataFrame)

min_date = minimum(fh_5[:, "date"])
max_date = maximum(fh_5[:, "date"])
date_seq = string.(collect(Dates.Date(min_date) : Dates.Day(1) : Dates.Date(max_date)))
date_range = df = DataFrame(dates = date_seq)
date_range.dates = Date.(date_range.dates, "yyyy-mm-dd")

for s in unique(fh_5.symbol)
    df = fh_5[fh_5.symbol .== s, ["date","close"]]
    date_range = leftjoin(date_range, df, on =:"dates" => :"date")
    rename!(date_range, Dict(:close => s))
end
size(date_range, 1)
size(filter(x -> any(!ismissing, x), date_range), 1)
size(date_range, 1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are working with DataFrames.jl. Then if `df` is your data frame just write:

```
filter(x -> any(!ismissing, x), df)
```

or `filter!` if you want an in-place operation.

Example:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Random

julia> Random.seed!(1234);

julia> df = DataFrame(rand([1, missing], 10, 2), :auto)
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2
     │ Int64?   Int64?
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │       1        1
   2 │ missing        1
   3 │ missing  missing
   4 │ missing  missing
   5 │       1        1
   6 │       1  missing
   7 │ missing  missing
   8 │       1  missing
   9 │       1        1
  10 │ missing        1

julia> filter(x -> any(!ismissing, x), df)
7×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2
     │ Int64?   Int64?
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │       1        1
   2 │ missing        1
   3 │       1        1
   4 │       1  missing
   5 │       1  missing
   6 │       1        1
   7 │ missing        1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not working for me the code is not deleting any of the rows - size(df,1) before and after running the code shared by you is the same. One more thing I am looking to remove only the rows which have all null values for all the columns - based on my search 'any' will remove the rows even if it has null values in any one of the column, I am getting very confused may be I am wrong. Can you please help

Comment: I have added an example to show you that what I propose works correctly. Could you please share your data so that it can be investigated? Also note that if you wanted to keep only rows that do not have any `missing` values then you should write `dropmissing(df)` instead (but this is not what you want if I understand your needs correctly).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help you understood my requirement correctly and your example is exactly what I want - I used your code but it is not working at my end - I used the data from the below link - [link] (https://www.kaggle.com/qks1lver/amex-nyse-nasdaq-stock-histories?select=fh_5yrs.csv) . I will edit my question and paste the full code for your reference, I have taken the data fh_5.csv which is around 700 MB from the link

Comment: you are not filtering anything because column `:dates` is not missing and you wanted to filter out rows that have ALL missing columns. Instead you want to filter out rows that have exactly ONE non-missing column, so the rule would be `filter(x -> count(!ismissing, x) == 1, date_range)` or `filter(x -> any(!ismissing, x[Not(1)]), df)`. Also note that instead of the loop you can just do `unstack(fh_5, :date, :symbol, :close)` instead of the loop which will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot - Its a very silly mistake - Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on Unstack  :) . It ran much faster as compared to for loop which I was using earlier - Thanks a lot